# How to create security rules for a REST API

Tags: python, angular, rest, flask, backend

I am working on a [Web App](https://github.com/celoubao/inventory-manager) with an Angular 2 frontend and a Flask backend that access a PostgreSQL database. My app sends requests to my backend such as `GET /items/{user_id}`, `GET /items/{user_id}/{item_id}` and `POST /items/{user_id}/{item_id}`

I am relatively new to Web Development and its my first time designing a REST API, how do I allow a user to only be able to access items under his user_id ? For example, if their user_id=123 `GET /items/123` would work but `GET /items/234` would not ?

Is is something that is done from the PostgreSQL side or I do have to write logic in the backend code server code to do something like this: ?

```
if current_user.id != req.params.user_id:
    // Send response status 403
else
    // Send response 200 with items as the body
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a pretty broad question with a lot of exceptions, I'll be pretty general. But this should be represented as a One-to-Many/Many-to-One relation within your database. In other words, a User can own multiple Items, but an Item can only be owned by one User. You'll want to have a Foreign Key constraint within your Items table that represents a `user_id`, or the ID of the owner. From their you'll want to query the database for only items that match the requesting User's ID.

In terms of keeping users from requesting other items, you might have to implement some kind of middleware that runs on your backend to check when a user is requesting a specific item that returns an error if they do not own it (Like what you suggested).

To be honest though, if its security you are concerned about you should consider restructuring your API calls. Since you are determining identity based on the `user_id` parameter within the url you are opening yourself up to users changing their advertised ID at will. Using web tokens to establish identity will go a long way in terms of beefing up the security of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your Insight. I know you were trying to be general but it was very useful. I think a web token as identity + a middleware and properly setup foreign keys in the database will be a good start toward a more secure web app